# Railo 4 - which document formats are supported by Cfindex / Lucene?

Tags: coldfusion, lucene, apache-poi, railo, cfindex

I thought i had a simple question, but somehow i cant find a source for the answer....which document formats can be indexed by the Lucene version that is packaged with Railo 4.0?

Somehow .doc and .pdf seem to go well, but docx and rtf just don't seem to get indexed....Is there a list available somewhere? And for all formats that arent supported, what would be the best way to get that info indexed aswell by cfindex?

```
        <cfindex 
        collection = "#collection#"   
        action = "update"   
        type = "file"
        key ="#ABSfilepath#"
        title="#ABSfilepath#"
        >
```

thanks!

Question also posted to Railo mailing list: [web link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/jmyX1JlGn70).

Comment: Looks like you also posted the question on the Railo Google Group.  Since the Railo folks monitor that group pretty closely, you are more likely to get a definitive answer to this particular question over there than here.

Comment: hi - i agree...just using all channels that might help ;-)

Comment: When you post in multiple places, **mention it and provide links** - both for the benefit of future searchers and so that potential answerers can check if they'd be wasting their time repeating what someone has already said elsewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Railo 4 uses Lucene 2.4.1** - how do you tell? Same way you tell the version for all third-party software that Railo uses: locate the JAR file (in the lib/ext directory), open that archive (using 7-zip or equivalent), and look at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF where you find content like this:

> Specification-Title: Lucene Search Engine: core
>   Specification-Version: 2.4.1
>   Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
>   Implementation-Title: org.apache.lucene
>   Implementation-Version: 2.4.1 750176 - 2009-03-04 21:56:52
>   Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation

This seems to be a pretty old version and doesn't look like it has any docs on the [Apache Lucene website](https://lucene.apache.org/core/documentation.html). (It *might* be possible to upgrade Lucene by replacing the relevant JARs, but this might also cause dependency issues; do at own risk.)

Since the Lucene website doesn't help, a search for "lucene 2.4.1 indexable documents" brings back [a pertinent question about v2.3.2](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/62413) which asks:

> Does Lucene java supports parsing of extensions *.docx, *.pptx, *.mpp i.e. 
>   Microsoft Windows 2007 documents?

With the response:

> Lucene doesn't actually support any of the document types. What happens 
>   is that some program is used to parse the files into an indexable stream 
>   and that stream is indexed. That used to be POI in the old days.

Ok, so assuming that is still accurate,  Lucene doesn't control the filetypes, [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) does.

Checking the JARs tells us Railo 4.0 uses Apache POI v3.8 and looking at the [POI changelog](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html) reveals that .docx support arrived in v3.5

So, **your .docx files should be supported** along with the other MS Office formats. If it's definitely not being indexed, you probably need to identify if it's a POI issue or a Lucene issue or a Railo issue - creating a simple reproducable test case with both .doc and .docx documents is probably a good first step.

Beyond that, you'll need someone familiar with Lucene/POI to advise - there may or not be log files that will contain details of possible indexing/retrieval errors, or ways to interact with Lucene directly (not via Railo/cfindex) that can help identify where the issue lies.

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks for your extensive answer. I will need to dig into the reason why specific fileformats are defintively not being indexed and others are.
And should there be someone with the specific Lucene/POI knowledge about logging etc...pls!